# How to obtain authentication token using urllib2 in python?

Tags: python, curl

I want to obtain authentication token using `urllib2` in python.
My program is (I changed credentials):

```
import urllib2
import urllib

USER_NAME = 'me'
USER_PASSWORD = 'mypass'

url = "http://myurl.org/oauth/token"

query_args = { "grant_type":"password",
               "username":USER_NAME,
               "password":USER_PASSWORD,
               "client_secret":'123',
                'client_id':'456'}

encoded_args = urllib.urlencode(query_args)
print urllib2.urlopen(url, data=encoded_args).read()
```

The result of running is `403 Error: Forbidden`.
However I can obtain the authentication token using `curl` in terminal:

```
curl -X POST "url" -d "credentials"
```

I used "url" and "credentials" from the python code (to obtain "credentials" string I prinded out `encoded_args`).

How to get authentication token using `urllib2`?

Comment: use try-except to log the full error response. maybe it's useful...

Comment: and you are really using HTTPS, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't mix `urllib` and `urllib2` in the same application. `urllib2` is the successor to `urllib`, and will do the same things.

The real answer here is to use an OAuth capable library to like [python-oauth2](https://github.com/brosner/python-oauth2) to do the heavy lifting for you. Or better, switch from `urllib2` to a slightly higher level package like [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/), and use one of their [brilliant oauth plugins](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-oauth) for a single solution which kicks some ass!